# Contact Form is not working anymore since upgrading from Craft 3 to 4

Tags: form, craft4

After upgrading to Craft 4 non of my Craft Forms are working... getting the error "Symfony\Component\Mime\Address::__construct(): Argument #2 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in /html/JANS-Staging/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer/src/Message.php on line 368" ... any idea please?

Also: For me the example code from here https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/ is working on a fresh installed Craft 4 version, but not on an upgraded one from 3 to 4...  not receiving any mail.

This is my form code:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form" id="form-jans-contact" autocomplete="off">
      {{ csrfInput() }}
      <input id="Gr3tHousesComeToLIf3" name="Gr3tHousesComeToLIf3" type="text">
      <input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{'marcelboer@me.com'|hash}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{"career.application"|translate}} - {{entry.title}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="contact-form/send">
      {{ redirectInput(craft.entries.section('brochureConfirm').one.url) }}
      <div class="form-wrapper form-full">
        <div class="form-aside__left">
          <div class="form-tiles">
            <div class="form-tile">
              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-firstname">{{"form.yourFirstName"|translate}}*</label>
                    <input id="from-firstname" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.yourFirstName"|translate}}]" value="" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-lastname">{{"form.yourLastName"|translate}}*</label>
                    <input id="from-lastname" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.yourLastName"|translate}}]" value="" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-email">{{"form.emailaddress"|translate}}*</label>
                    <input id="from-email" class="form-input" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="{{ message.fromEmail ?? '' }}" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-phone">{{"form.phone"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-phone" class="form-input" type="tel" name="message[Telefon]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label form-label-files" for="from-files">{{"career.uploadFiles"|translate}}:</label>
                    <input class="form-input form-files" type="file" name="attachment[]" id="from-files" multiple>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-tile">
              <h4 class="form-tile__title">{{"form.yourAddress"|translate}} (Optional)</h4>
              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-7">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-street">{{"form.street"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-street" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.street"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row f-row-3">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-housenumber">{{"form.number"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-housenumber" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.number"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-zipcode">{{"form.zipcode"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-zipcode" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.zipcode"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-city">{{"form.city"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-city" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.city"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-country">{{"form.Country"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-country" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.Country"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row f-row-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="from-comment">{{"form.comment"|translate}}</label>
                    <input id="from-comment" class="form-input" type="text" name="message[{{"form.comment"|translate}}]" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-tile">
              <h4 class="form-tile__title">{{"form.moreComments"|translate}}</h4>
              <div class="form-column">
                <div class="form-row f-row-10">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label" for="message">{{"form.comment"|translate}}</label>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="message" class="form-input form-textarea" name="message[body]">{{ message.message ?? '' }}</textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-submit">
        <div class="form-end">
          <ul class="form-checkbox__list">
            <li class="form-checkbox _smaller-text">
              <input id="f-cb14" class="form-checkbox__input" name="message[{{"form.consent"|translate}}][]" type="checkbox" value="{{"form.consent.dataprivacy"|translate}}" required><label for="f-cb14">{{"form.consent.dataprivacy"|translate}}*</label>
            </li>
            <li class="form-checkbox _smaller-text">
              <input id="f-cb15" class="form-checkbox__input" name="message[{{"form.consent"|translate}}][]" type="checkbox" value="{{"form.consent.userdatas"|translate}}" required><label for="f-cb15">{{"form.consent.userdatas"|translate}}*</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <button id="contact-form-submit" class="button" type="submit" form="form-jans-contact" value="Submit" title="{{ 'form.submit.title.captcha'|translate }}">
          <div class="button__decor"></div>
          <span class="button-title">{{"form.send"|translate}}</span>
          <span class="button-arrow">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="35" height="20" class="button-arrow-1" viewBox="0 0 35 20"><defs><clipPath id="a"><rect width="35" height="20" transform="translate(1113 6721)" fill="#fafafa"/></clipPath></defs><g transform="translate(-1113 -6721)" clip-path="url(#a)"><g transform="translate(-1102 10350.023) rotate(-90)"><path d="M3622.151,2217.556v31" transform="translate(-2.798 -0.556)" fill="none" stroke="#0f0e0e" stroke-width="1"/><path d="M3613.023,2239l6.33,9,5.67-9" fill="none" stroke="#0f0e0e" stroke-width="1"/></g></g></svg>
          </span>
        </button>
        {{ craft.contactFormExtensions.recaptcha | raw }}
      </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

welcome to the CraftCMS StackExchange

I dug around on the `craftcms/contact-form` repo and [found an open issue](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/issues/228) for the same error you're describing.

Basically, (as things currently stand) you need to add a field to your form with the name `fromName` for it to successfully submit. With the upgrade to Craft 4 it seems that `fromName` joined `fromEmail` and `message` as required fields, though that wasn't documented properly.

You could either change up your "First Name" field a bit like so:

```
<input id="from-firstname" class="form-input" type="text" name="fromName" value="" required>
```

Or if you're using some JS on the frontend, you could add a hidden input field:

```
<input id="full-name" type="hidden" name="fromName" value="" />
```

...and then when your form's submit button is clicked, you could fetch the values of the `yourFirstName` and `yourLastName` field and join them and update the value of this hidden field, and then let the form submission proceed as normal. That might be a bit of a complex solution though depending on your familiarity with JS...

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Yes, i found out the same. So with Craft 3 it was working. But in Craft 4 those fields are required for the submit :)